# What is wrong with my counter in my for loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, counter

I'm a newbie in Python but I don't understand why I'm getting an error at this line, thanks in advance!

```
    bands = ("Journey", "REO Speedwagon", "Styx",
"Mr. Mister", "The Cure", "The Doobie Brothers",
"Neil Diamond", "The Beatles")

bandRatings = {}

for band in bands:
  print("Please rate this band: " + band + " (1-10)")
  answer = input (": ")
  bandRatings.update({band: answer})

counter = 0
numRatings = 0

print("\nHere comes a summary of your ratings:\n")
for band, rating in bandRatings.items():
  print(band + ": " + str(rating))
  counter = counter + rating
  numRatings = numRatings + 1

print("\nYour average rating is:", numRatings)
If I do that, that works perfectly, but I uncomment the line, I get this error:

    File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
        counter = counter + rating
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I don't understand why? Thanks! Have a good one!

Comment: Show your `bandRatings` values

Comment: The `rating` variable seems to be a string inside the loop. Check that by adding `print type(rating)` as the first line inside the loop. If it is coming in as a string, then change `counter = counter + int(rating)`

Answer (score 1):

Your `counter` is a number, but `rating` is a string (`input()` returns string). You should convert it to `int`:

```
for band in bands:
  print("Please rate this band: " + band + " (1-10)")
  answer = input (": ")
  bandRatings.update({band: int(answer)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, whatever you enter input it will be in the form of string, so you need to typecast your answer

```
answer = int(input (": "))
```

Comment: Shoot! working perfectly! I was focusing on the line commented since the reference was on that one, didn't think of getting back to typecast my variable! Thanks Ajay!

Comment: @Nicolas2020 - If this solved your problem. Please accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess the rating is string, not an int.
Try:

```py
counter = counter + int(rating) # (line commented)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is,

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

If you look closely in your code you will realize that you are trying to combine an `int` datatype with a `string` datatype which is not possible.

Hence, to make your code syntactically correct, you can change that line to,

```
counter = counter + int(rating)
```